# Is there a way to "lock" the status bar on WP8 (Lumia 920)?

Tags: 8.0, lumia

I am tired of swiping down the screen every time to see the status bar.

Is there a way to keep it static?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible because this part of the screen is also used by the apps and if some of the apps would have some kind of status bar on top you would have a hard time to see the difference...